# Trouble correctly returning object name in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, naming

I'm trying to automate making a series of the same plot using different objects; I'm working with S4 class phyloseq objects. When I use a for loop to iterate over a list of objects and try to use the object name as a title for each plot and in a filename for ggsave I can't quite get it to recognize the correct name, though it's making the correct plots for a given object in the list.

I've tried using variations of `deparse(substitute(object))` with `get()` and `quote()` and end up getting slightly different, but still off-target results.

```
    object_list <- c(object1, object2, object3)
    automate_graphs <- function(x){
      for(object in x){
        name <- deparse(substitute(object))
        ordination <- ordinate(object, "NMDS", "bray")
        plot <- plot_ordination(object, ordination) + ggtitle(label = name)
        ggsave(plot, filename=sprintf("NMDS_bray_%s.pdf", name), height=4, width=7)}}

    automate_graphs(object_list)
```

I'm expecting to save 3 pdfs named `NMDS_bray_object1`, `NMDS_bray_object2`, `NMDS_bray_object3`.

Instead I get `NMDS_bray_S4 object of class structure("phyloseq", package = "phyloseq")` (so it's saving the deparse of the object to the variable name rather than the substitution) or with quote I get `NMDS_bray_object` which I suppose is to be expected haha. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a named vector (list) of objects and iterate over the names:

```
object_list <- c(object1 = object1,object2 = object2,object3 = object3)

automate_graphs <- function(x){
    for(nm in names(x)){
        object <- x[nm] #Pick out the one named nm
        ordination <- ordinate(object, "NMDS", "bray")
        plot <- plot_ordination(object, ordination) + ggtitle(label = nm)
        ggsave(plot, filename=sprintf("NMDS_bray_%s.pdf", nm), height=4, width=7)
    }}

automate_graphs(object_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've been tinkering with your solution but still can't quite get it to work... seems like the issue is rooted in my objects being S4 class. The error that I get initially is ' Error in ordinate(object, "NMDS", "bray") : 
  Expected a phyloseq object or otu_table object.' I get the same if I add quotes around the object names on the left side of the "=" sign; but I get a different error if I add them to the right: Error in object_list[whole_roots] : invalid subscript type 'S4'

Answer (score 0):

@Joran thanks again for the help--it pushed me in the right direction to figuring out a solution, even if it's not the most elegant. I took the idea of generating a vector of names and then just created an extra variable to cycle through that vector. But this way it maintains the class of object and creates a separate list of corresponding names:

```
object_list <- c("object1" = object1, "object2" = object2, "object3" = object3)
automate_graphs <- function(x){
  names = names(x)
  obj_num = 1
  for(object in x){
    name <- names[obj_num]
    ordination <- ordinate(object, "NMDS", "bray")
    plot <- plot_ordination(object, ordination) + ggtitle(label = name)
    ggsave(plot, filename=sprintf("NMDS_bray_%s.pdf", name), height=4, width=7)

    obj_num = obj_num + 1
  }
}
automate_graphs(object_list)
```